# Calling a function from Spring Webflow to store in Database(MySQL)

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I have the following POJO class called ProcessOrder

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id;

private String productname;

private int customerid;

private String customerName;

private String shippingAdress;

private int productid;

private int quantity;

private int status;
```

And this class called CartItem

```
@Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int cartItemId;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "cartId")
@JsonIgnore
private Cart cart;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "productId")
private Product product;

private int quantity;
private double totalPrice;
```

and this class called Cart

```
@Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int cartId;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "cart", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<CartItem> cartItems;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "customerId")
@JsonIgnore
private Customer customer;

private double grandTotal;
```

The following class called CustomerOrder

```
 @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int customerOrderId;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "cartId")
private Cart cart;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "customerId")
private Customer customer;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "billingAddressId")
private BillingAddress billingAddress;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="shippingAddressId")
private ShippingAddress shippingAddress;
```

I have more classes but they are not relevant to the question.

There's also a spring weblfow with the following XML snippet.

```
<var name="order" class="com.emusicstore.model.CustomerOrder" />

<action-state id="processOrder">
    <evaluate expression="CartItemDaoImpl.removeAllCartItemsCart(order.cart)" />
    <transition to="thankCustomer" />
```

and the removeAllCartItemsCart function in CartItemDaoImpl is as follows

```
public void removeAllCartItemsCart(Cart cart) {
        List<CartItem> cartItems = cart.getCartItems();

    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    int cusid = cart.getCustomer().getCustomerId();
    System.out.println(cusid);

    for (CartItem item : cartItems) {
        int pid = item.getProduct().getProductId();
        Query query=session.createQuery("from ProcessOrder where customerid= ? and productid= ?");
        query.setInteger(0, cusid);
        query.setInteger(1, pid);
        ProcessOrder pOrder1 =(ProcessOrder) query.uniqueResult();
        if(pOrder1!=null){
            pOrder1.setStatus(5);   
            session.saveOrUpdate(pOrder1);
        }
        //query.executeUpdate();
        removeCartItem(item);
    }
}
```

Running this gives me an exception of which I'm attaching a screenshot. I can't figure out a way to get rid of it. Is it possible to connect to database after calling a function from the webflow?

[image: Exception Screenshot]

**EDIT 1**

Following is the stack trace

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/emusicstore] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutionException: Exception thrown executing [AnnotatedAction@6c10bd32 targetAction = [EvaluateAction@4ff1de7f expression = CartItemDaoImpl.removeAllCartItemsCart(order.cart), resultExpression = [null]], attributes = map[[empty]]] in state 'processOrder' of flow 'checkout' -- action execution attributes were 'map[[empty]]'] with root cause
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Property or field 'CartItemDaoImpl' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl' - maybe not public?
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:226)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:93)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:81)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueRef(CompoundExpression.java:51)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:87)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:131)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:299)
    at org.springframework.binding.expression.spel.SpringELExpression.getValue(SpringELExpression.java:84)
    at org.springframework.webflow.action.EvaluateAction.doExecute(EvaluateAction.java:75)
    at org.springframework.webflow.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:188)
    at org.springframework.webflow.execution.AnnotatedAction.execute(AnnotatedAction.java:145)
    at org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:51)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ActionState.doEnter(ActionState.java:101)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:194)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.execute(Transition.java:227)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.execute(FlowExecutionImpl.java:393)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.execute(RequestControlContextImpl.java:214)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.TransitionableState.handleEvent(TransitionableState.java:119)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.handleEvent(Flow.java:555)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.handleEvent(FlowExecutionImpl.java:388)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.handleEvent(RequestControlContextImpl.java:210)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.handleEvent(ViewState.java:232)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.resume(ViewState.java:196)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.resume(Flow.java:545)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:258)
    at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:169)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:183)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**EDIT 2**

CartItemDaoImpl

```
package com.emusicstore.dao.impl;

import com.emusicstore.dao.CartItemDao;
import com.emusicstore.model.Cart;
import com.emusicstore.model.CartItem;
import com.emusicstore.model.ProcessOrder;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.List;


@Repository
@Transactional
public class CartItemDaoImpl implements CartItemDao{

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void addCartItem(CartItem cartItem) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.saveOrUpdate(cartItem);
        session.flush();
    }

    public void removeCartItem (CartItem cartItem) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.delete(cartItem);
        session.flush();
    }


    public void removeAllCartItemsCart(Cart cart) {
        List<CartItem> cartItems = cart.getCartItems();

        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        int cusid = cart.getCustomer().getCustomerId();
        System.out.println(cusid);

        for (CartItem item : cartItems) {
            int pid = item.getProduct().getProductId();
            Query query=session.createQuery("from ProcessOrder where customerid= ? and productid= ?");
            query.setInteger(0, cusid);
            query.setInteger(1, pid);
            ProcessOrder pOrder1 =(ProcessOrder) query.uniqueResult();
            if(pOrder1!=null){
                pOrder1.setStatus(5);   
                session.saveOrUpdate(pOrder1);
            }
            //query.executeUpdate();
            removeCartItem(item);
        }
    }

    public void removeAllCartItems(Cart cart) {
        List<CartItem> cartItems = cart.getCartItems();
        for (CartItem item : cartItems) {
            removeCartItem(item);
        }
    }

    public CartItem getCartItemByProductId (int productId) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Query query = session.createQuery("from CartItem where productId = ?");
        query.setInteger(0, productId);
        session.flush();

        return (CartItem) query.uniqueResult();
    }
}
```

**EDIT 3**

Following is the stack trace after changing case of c in cartItemDaoImpl in webflow xml file

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/emusicstore] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutionException: Exception thrown executing [AnnotatedAction@29b58b72 targetAction = [EvaluateAction@37f210b1 expression = cartItemDaoImpl.removeAllCartItemsCart(order.cart), resultExpression = [null]], attributes = map[[empty]]] in state 'processOrder' of flow 'checkout' -- action execution attributes were 'map[[empty]]'] with root cause
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E:(pos 16): Method call: Method removeAllCartItemsCart(com.emusicstore.model.Cart) cannot be found on com.sun.proxy.$Proxy60 type
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.findAccessorForMethod(MethodReference.java:211)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:125)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.access$000(MethodReference.java:49)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference$MethodValueRef.getValue(MethodReference.java:342)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:88)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:131)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:299)
    at org.springframework.binding.expression.spel.SpringELExpression.getValue(SpringELExpression.java:84)
    at org.springframework.webflow.action.EvaluateAction.doExecute(EvaluateAction.java:75)
    at org.springframework.webflow.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:188)
    at org.springframework.webflow.execution.AnnotatedAction.execute(AnnotatedAction.java:145)
    at org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:51)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ActionState.doEnter(ActionState.java:101)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:194)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.execute(Transition.java:227)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.execute(FlowExecutionImpl.java:393)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.execute(RequestControlContextImpl.java:214)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.TransitionableState.handleEvent(TransitionableState.java:119)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.handleEvent(Flow.java:555)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.handleEvent(FlowExecutionImpl.java:388)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.handleEvent(RequestControlContextImpl.java:210)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.handleEvent(ViewState.java:232)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.resume(ViewState.java:196)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.resume(Flow.java:545)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:258)
    at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:169)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:183)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Following is the spring webflow xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd">

    <var name="order" class="com.emusicstore.model.CustomerOrder" />

    <action-state id="addCartToOrder">
        <evaluate expression="cartDaoImpl.validate(requestParameters.cartId)" result="order.cart" />
        <transition to="InvalidCartWarning" on-exception="java.io.IOException" />
        <transition to="collectCustomerInfo" />
    </action-state>

    <view-state id="collectCustomerInfo" view="collectCustomerInfo.jsp" model="order">
        <transition on="customerInfoCollected" to="collectShippingDetail" />
    </view-state>

    <view-state id="collectShippingDetail" view="collectShippingDetail.jsp" model="order">
        <transition on="shippingDetailCollected" to="orderConfirmation" />
        <transition on="backToCollectCustomerInfo" to="collectCustomerInfo" />
    </view-state>

    <view-state id="orderConfirmation">
        <transition on="orderConfirmed" to="processOrder" />
        <transition on="backToCollectShippingDetail" to="collectShippingDetail" />
    </view-state>

    <action-state id="processOrder">
        <evaluate expression="cartItemDaoImpl.removeAllCartItemsCart(order.cart)" /> 
        <transition to="thankCustomer" />
    </action-state>

    <view-state id="thankCustomer" model="order">
        <transition to="endState" />
    </view-state>

    <end-state id="endState" />

    <view-state id="invalidCartWarning">
        <transition to="endState" />
    </view-state>

    <end-state id="cancelCheckout" view="checkOutCancelled.jsp" />

    <global-transitions>
        <transition on="cancel" to="cancelCheckout" />
    </global-transitions>
</flow>
```

Also I just I want to highlight that if I just change the removeAllCartItemsCart method to

```
public void removeAllCartItemsCart(Cart cart) {
        List<CartItem> cartItems = cart.getCartItems();
        for (CartItem item : cartItems) {

            removeCartItem(item);
        }
    }
```

It works pretty well. So I'm guessing it has something to do with me trying to execute a query there.

Comment: Please, add the stacktrace from a log (not an image from a browser).

Comment: @v.ladynev Editted the question.

Comment: you are not using the proper bean name for your CartItemDaoImpl. my guess would be `cartItemDaoImpl` or `cartItemDao`

Comment: can you please post the code for `CartItemDaoImpl`

Comment: @rptmat57 'removeAllCartItemsCart' function is in the 'CartItemDaoImpl'. I also posted the full 'CartItemDaoImpl' is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the annotation `@Repository` is creating a bean with a default name of `cartItemDaoImpl`.

you can find out about the default naming convention [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.html).

so, you should use

```
<evaluate expression="cartItemDaoImpl.removeAllCartItemsCart(order.cart)" />
```

starting with a lowercase `c`

or keep you code but change your annotation to `@Repository("CartItemDaoImpl")`

[UPDATE]

you now have a different issue. you are using @Transactional but with Spring AOP the Aspects will only work if they are on a method present in the interface due to the proxying.

So what you have to do now is add `void removeAllCartItemsCart(Cart cart);` to your interface `CartItemDao`.

Comment: I corrected that. But it still does not work. The same error.

Comment: can you post your webflow configuration file?

Comment: and update the stack trace the error should be slightly different

Comment: Could you please look at another similar question?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44111348/spring-webflow-action-execution-exception